# DXF File with text labels not showing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, svg, dxf, illustrator

I convert a CDR. file to SVG. using [cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/cdr-to-svg) then i opened the SVG. file in Adobe Illustrator it was a vector map with text labels. I then export the file from Adobe Illustrator in DXF. format. I opened the DXF as vector layer in QGIS but the text labels are gone. What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup labeling manually via layer setting dialog. Select "Text" filed as label source.

[image]